# Cumulative sum of dataframe up to a certain line (row)

Tags: r, cumsum

I would like to have cumulative sum of following data:

```
    c1    c2    c3
    
1     3     6     3
2     4     3     2
3     6     2     5
4     1     5     4
5     0     0     0
6     0     0     0
```

but up to 4th line (row). For example, a following code with produce general cumulative sum of dataframe including all the rows over the columns

```
library(readxl)
library(xts)
library("xlsx")
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

D <- structure(list(c1 = c(3, 4, 6, 1, 0, 0), c2 = c(6, 3, 2, 5, 0, 
0), c3 = c(3, 2, 5, 4, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
D
csD <- cumsum(D)
csD
```

resulting with

```
     c1    c2    c3
    
1     3     6     3
2     7     9     5
3    13    11    10
4    14    16    14
5    14    16    14
6    14    16    14
```

However, I would like to have:

```
     c1    c2    c3
    
1     3     6     3
2     7     9     5
3    13    11    10
4    14    16    14
5     0     0     0
6     0     0     0
```

Thank you in advance. Alan

Comment: Hello, what is exactly the rule saying when the `cumsum` should stop? Always 4 rows? When 0 is encountered?

Comment: The expected output is not actually columnwise cumulative sum, but something else including extra conditions. Maybe resetting the cumulative sum when encountering zero values?

Comment: Which arguments would your desired conditional cumulative sum function have?

Comment: No, not always, 4 rows, actually, up to n-th row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the most optimal way but you can define `N` and use `apply()` and `rbind()` like this:

```
#Code
#Define N
N <- 4
#Compute
newdf <- rbind(apply(D,2,function(x) cumsum(x[1:N])),
               D[(N+1):nrow(D),])
```

Output:

```
newdf
  c1 c2 c3
1  3  6  3
2  7  9  5
3 13 11 10
4 14 16 14
5  0  0  0
6  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
csD*(D!=0)
  c1 c2 c3
1  3  6  3
2  7  9  5
3 13 11 10
4 14 16 14
5  0  0  0
6  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> rbind(cumsum(D[1:(min(which(rowSums(D) == 0))-1), ]), cumsum(D[min(which(rowSums(D) == 0)):nrow(D), ]))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     c1    c2    c3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     6     3
2     7     9     5
3    13    11    10
4    14    16    14
5     0     0     0
6     0     0     0
>
```

Comment: Thank you, all examples (solutions) work, but I think that Duck's is actually I was looking for! Once again - huge thanks to all of you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the `NA` to 0 (`na_if`), get the `cumsum` and replace the `NA`with 0 (`replace_na`) `across` all the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
D %>% 
       mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(cumsum(na_if(., 0)), 0)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#     c1    c2    c3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3     6     3
#2     7     9     5
#3    13    11    10
#4    14    16    14
#5     0     0     0
#6     0     0     0
```

---

Or if we want to specify a row number

```
D %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(row_number() <=4 ~
        cumsum(.), TRUE ~ .)))
```